Decide on a templated class whether it holds 2 variables or just 1
I want to have a nested class B that behaves as follows:

if T is void, then B has only one member field sz and sizeof(B) == sizeof(sz)

otherwise, B has a member field sz and somehow obtains T


#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A {

  struct B {
    size_t sz;
    
    if (T != void)
    T t;  // declare T field
  };

};

I have found this partial solution but it works for integral types only and has some inconveniences in accessing T data.
static constexpr bool is_void = std::is_same_v<void, T>;
using type = std::conditional_t<is_void, bool, T>;

struct B {
  size_t sz;
  type : (is_void ? 0 : sizeof(type));
  // if 'type' has a name, possible CE: Named bit-field has zero width
};

Alternatively, we can create something similar with the inheritance trick but I want to find other ways (no boilerplate code) the language provides (~specifically created for such cases).
struct empty_class {};
struct container { T t; };  // solves (std::is_class_v<T> && !std::is_final_v<T>)

static constexpr bool is_void = std::is_same_v<void, T>;
using base = std::conditional_t<is_void, empty_class, container>;

struct B : base {
  size_t sz;
};

Potentially, the specialization of A<void> can create a lot of boilerplate code.
Commentary
For clarity: I want universe std::__detail::__extent_storage that std::span has (it stores everything, except for void)

I anticipate the commentaries about union (std::variant) but, please, mind: T == void <=> sizeof(B) == sizeof(sz)

What's the reason for "I want to find other ways"? There aren't ready solutions for every situation and you often need some boilerplate.

All these questions about introspection these days. Why not write code that doesn’t need it?

I thought C++ might have a ready solution for this case (metaprogramming never ends). I'm also (+-) self studying and want to discover all corners of the C++ Standard.

Even when a specialization of all of A isn't a viable option, you can specialize just the part that absolutely needs it.
Here, the only difference between the two cases is whether T t exists or not.
Approach A - Inheritance
template <typename T>
struct maybe {
  T t;
};

template <>
struct maybe<void> { };

template <typename T>
class A {
  struct B : maybe<T> {
    std::size_t sz;
  };
};

Having a base class of type maybe<void> should not add anything to the size of B because of empty base class optimization.
Approach B - std::conditional_t
struct empty { };

template <typename T>
class A {
  struct B {
    std::size_t sz;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, void>, empty, T> t;
  };
};

This approach should also not cost any size increase if t is of type empty, however, it pollutes B with a possibly unwanted empty t member.
Approach C - Specialize B
template <typename T>
class A {
  struct B {
    std::size_t sz;
    T t;
  };
};

template <>
struct A<void>::B {
    std::size_t sz;
};

This approach wouldn't require specializing all of A, but all of B.
It may be the most redundant in a larger example, but it is the cleanest and simplest.

What about replacing empty with std::byte[0]? ([[no_unique_address]] is even not needed)

@AlexanderS there are no zero-size arrays in C++ (not counting compiler extensions).

As an alternative the user can replace empty with std::tuple<>, which is supported in C++

off-topic   Additionally, there is a slight advantage of placing std::conditional_t before std::size_t because

I don't see a way that sz could use any of the padding potentially left by t, since it is aligned to 8 bytes (usually) already. Well, I guess if T is more aligned (such as to 16 bytes), then you would have some padding between members to align t, and the padding cannot be repurposed. However, if sz is more aligned, then the other way around would leave a gap to align sz. I don't think you can make a general statement about where t should go, given that T can by any type with any alignment.

You could simply specialize A for void:
template <typename T>
class A {
  struct B {
    size_t sz;
    T t;
  };
};

template <>
class A<void> {
  struct B {
    size_t sz;
  };
};

Example:
A<int>::B b1;
b1.t // OK, t exists

A<void>::B b2;
b2.t // error, t does not exist


Sorry, I forgot to mention that we do not specialize A<void> and that specialization of B is impossible

@AlexanderS Please update your question to explain why that is not a viable solution for your use-case.
